# Ionic 3 - Storage Persists Only Once

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

Okay, so this is a weird one, and I'm sure there's a perfectly good explanation for it, but it eludes me. The basics:

- I have a provider that has a nested list of objects.
- Anytime I update an object in that list, I save the updated list to storage in the `LogGoals` function.
- The first time I run the app after installing (or the first time it loads after `ionic serve`) the list successfully saves.
- If I close and reload the app (or refresh the browser in the case of serving), I can see my changes. If I make more changes, though, the nested list doesn't update.

---

Here is the provider in question:

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';


@Injectable()
export class GoalproviderProvider {

  public all_goals:any = [];
  public viewed_tutorial = false;

  public style_options = [
    {
      style_name: "girl-and-dog",
      style_color: "#5bc3cc",
      style_icon: "md-paw",
      style_icon_color: "#FFFFFF",
      mood: "Joyous"
    },
    {
      style_name: "pink-city",
      style_color: "#f7ced9",
      style_icon: "md-radio",
      style_icon_color: "#FFFFFF",
      mood: "Serene"
    },
    {
      style_name: "snow-guy",
      style_color: "#b4cbb9",
      style_icon: "md-snow",
      style_icon_color: "#FFFFFF",
      mood: "Confident"
    },
    {
      style_name: "fish-shop",
      style_color: "#31c1e9",
      style_icon: "md-rainy",
      style_icon_color: "#FFFFFF",
      mood: "Relaxed"
    }
  ];

  constructor(public http: HttpClient,
              private storage: Storage) {
    console.log('Loading Goals');
    this.LoadGoals();
  }

  public ClearAllData() {
    this.storage.clear();
  }

  public GetWatchedGoals() {
    var watched_goals = [];
    var i = 0;
    while(i < this.all_goals.length) {
      var k = 0;
      while(k < this.all_goals[i].goal_list.length) {
        var child_watched_goals = this.GetWatchedGoalsRecursively(this.all_goals[i].goal_list[k]);
        watched_goals = watched_goals.concat(child_watched_goals);
        k++;
      }
      i++;
    }
    return watched_goals;
  }

  public GetWatchedGoalsRecursively(goal) {
    var watched_goals = [];
    if(goal.goal_watch && !goal.goal_complete && !goal.goal_deleted)
      watched_goals.push(goal);
    var i = 0;
    while(i < goal.goal_list.length) {
      var child_watched_goals = this.GetWatchedGoalsRecursively(goal.goal_list[i]);
      watched_goals = watched_goals.concat(child_watched_goals);
      i++;
    }
    return watched_goals;
  }

  public AppendAndReturnNewGoal(goal_style, goal_title) {
    var new_goal = {
      goal_style: goal_style,
      goal_title: goal_title,
      goal_list: [],
      goal_id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds()
    };
    this.all_goals.push(new_goal);
    this.LogGoals();
    return new_goal;
  }

  public EditGoalTitle(goal, new_title) {
    goal.goal_title = new_title;
    this.LogGoals();
  }

  public AddGoalChild(goal, new_title) {
    var new_goal = {
      goal_title: new_title,
      goal_watch: false,
      goal_complete: false,
      goal_deleted: false,
      goal_list: [],
      goal_id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds()
    }
    goal.goal_list.push(new_goal);
    this.LogGoals();
  }

  public AddGoalParent(goal, new_title) {
    var new_goal = {
      goal_title: goal.goal_title,
      goal_watch: goal.goal_watch,
      goal_complete: goal.goal_complete,
      goal_deleted: goal.goal_deleted,
      goal_list: goal.goal_list,
      goal_id: goal.goal_id
    }
    goal.goal_title = new_title;
    goal.goal_watch = false;
    goal.goal_complete = false;
    goal.goal_deleted = false;
    goal.goal_list = [ new_goal ];
    goal.goal_id = new Date().getUTCMilliseconds();
    this.LogGoals();
  }

  public DeleteGoal(goal) {
    goal.goal_deleted = true;
    this.LogGoals();
  }

  public ToggleGoalComplete(goal) {
    goal.goal_complete = !goal.goal_complete;
    this.LogGoals();
  }

  public ToggleGoalWatch(goal) {
    goal.goal_watch = !goal.goal_watch;
    this.LogGoals();
  }

  public UpdateMasterGoal(goal_id, new_goal) {

  }

  LogGoals() {
    // TODO : I THINK WE HAVE TO TIMEOUT THIS FUNCTION TO ALLOW "ALL_GOALS" TO CATCH UP.
    console.log('GOAL LOG:', this.all_goals);
    this.storage.set('all_goals', this.all_goals);
  }

  LoadGoals() {
    this.all_goals = [];
    this.storage.get('all_goals').then((val) => {
      if(!val) {
        val = [];
        this.storage.set('all_goals', val);
      }
      console.log('GOALS LOADED FROM STORAGE:', val);
      this.all_goals = val;
    });
  }
}
```

---

In this snippet, I have a variable `all_goals`. This variable is connected to a series of recursive components that have the ability to update/manipulate their respective goal.

The Component:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActionSheetController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { GoalproviderProvider } from '../../providers/goalprovider/goalprovider';
import { MonetizationProvider } from '../../providers/monetization/monetization';


@Component({
  selector: 'goalem-list',
  templateUrl: 'goalem.html'
})
export class GoalemComponent {

 @Input() goal_list;
 @Input() search_term;
 @Input() nested_level;

 constructor(public actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController,
    public alertCtrl: AlertController,
    public goal_provider: GoalproviderProvider,
    public monetization_provider: MonetizationProvider) {
  
 }

   PresentActionSheet(goal) {
   const actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
     title: goal.goal_title,
     buttons: [
       {
         text: 'Add Step',
         icon: 'add-circle',
         handler: () => {
           console.log('Add Child Step');
           this.PresentAddChildPopup(goal);
         }
       },
       {
         text: 'Add Parent Step',
         icon: 'add-circle',
         handler: () => {
           console.log('Add Parent Step');
           this.PresentAddParentPopup(goal);
         }
       },
       {
         text: goal.goal_complete ? 'Mark Incomplete' : 'Mark Complete',
         icon: goal.goal_complete ? 'close-circle' : 'checkmark-circle',
         handler: () => {
           console.log('Check Off');
           this.goal_provider.ToggleGoalComplete(goal);
         }
       },
       {
         text: 'Edit',
         icon: 'build',
         handler: () => {
           console.log('Edit Goal');
           this.PresentEditPopup(goal);
         }
       },
       {
         text: goal.goal_watch ? 'Stop Watching' : 'Watch',
         icon: goal.goal_watch ? 'eye-off' : 'eye',
         handler: () => {
           console.log('Watch Goal');
           this.goal_provider.ToggleGoalWatch(goal);
         }
       },
       {
         text: 'Delete',
         icon: 'trash',
         role: 'destructive',
         handler: () => {
           console.log('Delete Goal');
           this.PromptConfirmDelete(goal);
         }
       },
       {
         text: 'Cancel',
         icon: 'close',
         role: 'cancel',
         handler: () => {
           console.log('Cancel clicked');
         }
       }
     ]
   });
   actionSheet.present();
 }

 PresentEditPopup(goal) {
     const prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
       title: 'Edit Step',
       message: "Enter a description for this step.",
       inputs: [
         {
           name: 'title',
           placeholder: 'Description...',
           value: goal.goal_title
         },
       ],
       buttons: [
         {
           text: 'Cancel',
           handler: data => {
             console.log('Cancel clicked');
           }
         },
         {
           text: 'Submit',
           handler: data => {
             this.goal_provider.EditGoalTitle(goal, data.title);
           }
         }
       ]
     });
     prompt.present();
   }

   PresentAddChildPopup(goal) {
    if(this.nested_level > 3) {
     var limit_title = "It's goals all the way down, mate.";
        var limit_description = "You've discovered a premium feature! To unlock your app's true potential, click the button below. Your donation helps cover our operating costs, allowing us to continue providing the fantastic service you deserve!";
        if(this.monetization_provider.PromptUpgradeIfNotPremium(limit_title, limit_description))
          return;
    }
     const prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
       title: 'Create Step',
       message: "Enter a description for this step.",
       inputs: [
         {
           name: 'title',
           placeholder: 'Description...'
         },
       ],
       buttons: [
         {
           text: 'Cancel',
           handler: data => {
             console.log('Cancel clicked');
           }
         },
         {
           text: 'Submit',
           handler: data => {
             this.goal_provider.AddGoalChild(goal, data.title);
           }
         }
       ]
     });
     prompt.present();
   }

   PresentAddParentPopup(goal) {
     const prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
       title: 'Create Step',
       message: "Enter a description for this step.",
       inputs: [
         {
           name: 'title',
           placeholder: 'Description...'
         },
       ],
       buttons: [
         {
           text: 'Cancel',
           handler: data => {
             console.log('Cancel clicked');
           }
         },
         {
           text: 'Submit',
           handler: data => {
             this.goal_provider.AddGoalParent(goal, data.title);
           }
         }
       ]
     });
     prompt.present();
   }

   PromptConfirmDelete(goal) {
     const confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
       title: 'Are You Sure?',
       message: 'By deleting this step, you will also delete any children steps. This can not be undone. Continue?',
       buttons: [
         {
           text: 'Cancel',
           handler: () => {
             console.log('Disagree clicked');
           }
         },
         {
           text: 'Okay',
           handler: () => {
             this.goal_provider.DeleteGoal(goal);
           }
         }
       ]
     });
     confirm.present();
 }

}
```

```html
<ul *ngIf="goal_list.length">
 <li *ngFor="let goal of goal_list">
  <ion-item class="goal-item" *ngIf="!goal.goal_deleted && (!search_term || goal.goal_title.toLowerCase().includes(search_term.toLowerCase()))">
      <p [ngStyle]="{'text-decoration': goal.goal_complete ? 'line-through' : 'none'}">{{goal.goal_title}}</p>
      <button ion-button clear item-end (tap)="PresentActionSheet(goal);">
       <ion-icon name="md-menu"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-item>
  <goalem-list [goal_list]="goal.goal_list" [search_term]="search_term" [nested_level]="nested_level + 1" *ngIf="goal.goal_list.length && !goal.goal_deleted"></goalem-list>
 </li>
</ul>
```

You can see that the component calls itself. This creates a nested series of components that mirrors the nested list of goals from the provider.

Functionally, everything works right except the saving. Here's what I've discovered so far:

- The first time the app runs, everything updates correctly. `all_goals` always mirrors the goal tree. Anytime I make an update to the goal tree it "syncs" back to the `all_goals` variable in the provider.
- After restarting, the syncing doesn't work. I can make manipulations to the components and they work, but they are no longer bound to `all_goals`. all_goals loads from storage and then never changes. So anytime I save it to storage it's not writing any of the updates (because the variable didn't update).
- **Update:** Further findings. While serving, anytime the app rebuilds, saving to storage works *once* and then refreshing causing it to stop working again. So the following actions stop storage from working: closing and opening the app on a mobile device, or refreshing the browser while saving. And the following actions cause it to work until one of the previously mentioned actions occurs: serving the app, rebuilding the app (by modifying code while serving), or reinstalling the app on the mobile device.

I'm a bit frazzled, and this is nearing the edge of my skillset, so unsure how to work on debugging. For reference, here is the page that calls the very root `goal-list` component.

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar class="overlapping-navbar">
    <button ion-button menuToggle icon-only>
      <ion-icon name='menu'></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="search_term" placeholder="Search..."></ion-input>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content scroll="false" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': goal_color}">
  <div class="splash-bg">
    <img [src]="goal_image" />
  </div>
  <div class="splash-info">
    <!-- <div class="splash-logo"></div> -->
    <div class="splash-goal">
      <div>
        {{goal_title}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="goal-list">
    <goalem-list [goal_list]="goal_list" [search_term]="search_term" [nested_level]="1" *ngIf="goal_list"></goalem-list>
    <button class="rpg-button" ion-button icon-end large (click)="PromptForNewGoal()"
            style="margin:auto; display:block; margin-top:35px;">
        Map It!
    </button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

If there is anything I can do to provide more information just let me know :) I think the issue stems from the nesting, but what confuses me is that it *works* the first time. So strange...

Comment: Perhaps it has to do with the LoadGoals function? That's the only item that would operate differently between loads.